# Google cloud sdk error : token exchange failed

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-registry, google-cloud-shell

I am totally new to Google Cloud. I am trying to push a Docker image on Google Cloud Registry. 
I have performed following steps :

1. Installed Google Cloud SDK.
2. Downloaded a JSON key file for my IM account
3. Set authentication using following command:

   `google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file <path_to_json_file>`
4. Executed below command for login:

   `docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://asia.gcr.io < path_to_json_file`

   Now, when I am trying to push my image on my registry, with following command :

   `docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://asia.gcr.io <path_to_json_file>`

I am getting an error on my SDK shell :

```
token exchange failed : Access denied.
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the [official guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling) on how to push/pull?

Why are you trying to login? weren't you trying to push the image?

for example, if you are trying to push a nginx, the commands will be something like this:

```
$ gcloud auth configure-docker activate-service-account --key-file <path_to_json_file>

$ docker tag simple-nginx eu.gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/simple-nginx

$ docker push eu.gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/simple-nginx
```

Keep in mind that you will need to put your project ID, and the zone you want (being asia.gcr in our case i guess)